# Calling a String value from one class to another class

Tags: java, class, methods

Can anyone help me to call or retrieve the string "fam_acc_data" value from a class create_family child_tab to another class parent_search_process class?? Many thanks in advance.

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = "parent_form_inputs")
      public create_family child_tab(String parent_form2_error_image_path) throws IOException
      {
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

         if(driver.findElement(child_link).isDisplayed())
         {

             System.out.println("Parent Information Added Successfully");
             System.out.println("");    

             String fam_acc_data = driver.findElement(fam_acc_key).getText();
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("Some Error Occured Will Parent Creation");
             System.out.println("");

             File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
             FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(parent_form2_error_image_path));
             System.out.println("Refer the Screen Shot Saved in: " + parent_form2_error_image_path);
             System.out.println("");

         }

         return this;
      }
```

Comment: There is a thing called "static"

Comment: setters and getters usually do this

Comment: please help guys. i need a sample code...

Comment: are you want pass a string or get a string from another class?

Answer (score 0):

For Example in your class CreateFamily, you have a String name :

```
class CreateFamily{
private String name;

public String getName(){
return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
}
```

Now you need to get this name string in another class say ParentSearchProcess:-

```
CreateFamily createFamily=new CreateFamily();
String value="Some_name";
createFamily.setName(value); //for setting
createFamily.getName(); // for retrieving
```

Below is by using static:-

```
class class CreateFamily{
    public static String name;

    }
```

Now you can retrieve and set above value as below:-

```
CreateFamily.name="someValue"; //for setting
String value=CreateFamily.name; //for getting
```